# jQuery AJAX to upload picture => PHP sends back responseText with HTML instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

My goal is to **upload an image to PHP SYMFONY through jQuery AJAX**. Thanks to the input I got on some other SO thread, I manage to get the file going to the PHP side. Now the answer **I expect back from PHP to AJAX is a JSON**.

I can see my PHP creates the JSON and sends it back, but for some reasons (that I am suspecting being a PHP.INI setting) the AJAX Object has  in its `responseText` some HTML at the beginning of it:

```
"<br /> <b>Notice</b>:  Unknown: file created in the system's temporary directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br /> "{\u0022status\u0022:\u0022success\u0022,\u0022fileUploaded\u0022:true}""
```

My code on AJAX side looks like that:

```
var pictureFormData = new FormData();
pictureFormData.append('pictureFile', $(#[input_type_file_on_DOM_id])[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: [my php to integrate image].php,
    data: pictureFormData,
    type:"post",
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    cache:false,
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(res){
        console.log('AJAX SUCCESS');
        console.info(res);
    },
    error:function(err){
        console.log('AJAX ERR');
        console.info(err);

    },
    timeout:function(){
        console.log('AJAX TIMEOUT');
    },
    complete: function(){
        console.log('AJAX COMPLETE');

    }
});
```

On my PHP SYMFONY side the CONTROLLER dealing with the AJAX call looks like this:

```
class AjaxImageController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $file = $request->files->get('pictureFile');
        $status = array('status' => "success","fileUploaded" => false);

           // If a file was uploaded
           if(!is_null($file)){
              // generate a random name for the file but keep the extension
              $filename = uniqid().".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
              $path = "/tmp";
              $file->move($path,$filename); // move the file to a path
              $status = array('status' => "success","fileUploaded" => true);
           }
        $data = json_encode($status);


            $response = new JsonResponse();
            $response->setData($data);


        dump($response);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

As you can see I do a `dump(response)` just before sending it back. Its content is as follow:

```
JsonResponse {#719 ▼
  #data: ""{\u0022status\u0022:\u0022success\u0022,\u0022fileUploaded\u0022:true}""
  #callback: null
  #encodingOptions: 15
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#722 ▼
    #computedCacheControl: array:2 [▼
      "no-cache" => true
      "private" => true
    ]
    #cookies: []
    #headerNames: array:2 [▼
      "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
      "content-type" => "Content-Type"
    ]
    #headers: array:2 [▼
      "cache-control" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "no-cache, private"
      ]
      "content-type" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "application/json"
      ]
    ]
    #cacheControl: []
  }
  #content: ""{\u0022status\u0022:\u0022success\u0022,\u0022fileUploaded\u0022:true}""
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"
  #charset: null
}
```

Hence I don't get why the `responseText` is erroneous containing HTML at its begining with: `"<br /> <b>Notice</b>:  Unknown: file created in the system's
 temporary directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />"` and triggering then the `error` function of the AJAX call.

**SOME UPDATE**:
I notice the following:

On client side when I have `pictureFormData.append('pictureFile', $(#[input_type_file_on_DOM_id])[0].files[0]);` that is embedded in what I send to SYMFONY PHP Server: I notice in CONTROLLER incoming `$request` that the file appears in a FileBag Object:

```
Request {#9 ▼
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#12 ▶}
  +request: ParameterBag {#10 ▶}
  +query: ParameterBag {#11 ▶}
  +server: ServerBag {#16 ▶}
  +files: FileBag {#14 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "pictureFile" => UploadedFile {#15 ▼
        .... all files data
      }
    ]
  }
...
}
```

**AND THEN I GET THE ERROR I DESCRIBED**.

If I take away the file sent from the client side, and check the CONTROLLER, the `$request` looks like this:

```
   Request {#9 ▼
...      +files: FileBag {#14 ▼
        #parameters: []
      }
    ...
    }
```

In that case the error does not show up. I suspect hence an operation on the FileBag object to throw an `echo` somehow.

Comment: You don't need to encode the date before sending it. That's what `ResponseJson` does by default. `return ResponseJson(array $data, ...)` will work just fine. You're forcing a header output because of the error prior to actually sending the appropriate header. Get rid of the error and things should be working smoothly.

Comment: You mean to do `$response->setData($status)` instead of passing `$status` thru `$data = json_encode($status)` and then do `$response->setData($data)`. I did try it, it replaces the unicode char \u022 by regular quotes but still get same error on client side.

Comment: I mean you can simply use [the construct](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php#L42) without needing to `json_encode` the values prior. Either way, the error is not related to the json_encode part.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is containing HTML because php throw an error. If you correct it, then the reponse will be good.

It seem like the file doesn't exist.

If you don't see the file on your server, or in your XHR request then you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form.

If the form and XHR request are OK, then try upload your file with adding root directory to your upload directory.

```
# app/config/config.yml

# ...
parameters:
    brochures_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/brochures'
```

and

```
$file->move(
    $this->getParameter('brochures_directory'),
    $fileName
);
```

or just in your controller

```
$root = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
$path = $root."/tmp";
$file->move($path,$filename); // move the file to a path
```

Comment: thanks for the input. I had already tried with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` it does not change anything. The change of the file location does not change anything. Even I comment the whole chunk of code that does something with the file, I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to PHP.INI settings:

the folder:
**upload_tmp_dir = [path to php]\php7\uploadtemp** was set in PHP.INI.

"[path to php]\php7\" existed but not folder "uploadtemp" and it couldn't create it.

I created the folder "uploadtemp" in "[path to php]\php7\" and it solved it.